# Better Alternative to MongoDB db.collection.group()

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking to group a collection of documents, then format them into something I can query dynamically,  then query on the resulting collection. I've been able to group the collection and format it successfully using `db.collection.group()` but there are limitations when it comes to sharding that would prevent me from using it in production.

Here's that code:

```
var reduceFunction = function(current, result){
  var provider = current.provider;
  var collection = current.collection || provider;
  result[provider] = result[provider] || {};

  result[provider][collection] = result[provider][collection] || {};

  result[provider][collection] = current.attributes;
}


var result = db.identity.group( {
   key: { cookie: 1 },
   cond: { organizationId: organization },
   reduce: reduceFunction,
   initial: {}
} );
```

Here's an example of the input documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566c92712ae892aeb5278467"),
    "provider" : "myProvider",
    "collection": "myCollection",
    "ip" : 111.111.111.111,
    "cookie" : "12381902348asdf",
    "updated" : ISODate("2015-12-12T21:32:33.824Z"),
    "attributes" : {
        company: "My Company"
    }
}
```

Here's what my desired output would be (multiple input documents grouped by cookie)

```
{
    "cookie" : "12381902348asdf",
    "myProvider": {
      "myCollection": {
        "company": "myCompany"
      }
    },
    "myOtherProvider": {
      "myOtherCollection": {
        "company": "myCompany"
      }
    }
}
```

so that way I could query using something like

```
collection.identity.find({"myProvider.myCollection.company": {$regex: /my/}})
```

This allows me to have conditions for multiple provider/collection/field groupings without having conflicts in the field names.

Comment: [db.collection.aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)

Comment: @user3100115 I guess the only thing that I don't understand about using the aggregate pipeline is how I can create dynamic keys with it. I need to be able to query for { '$provider.$collection.$<field>': <conditions>} and this group function lets me do that but the aggregate won't. any advice?

Comment: Actually your question is hard to understand. Can you please tell us what you're trying to do? also please add sample document with expected result.

Comment: @user3100115 thanks for clarifying what I should add, I added the sample documents and what I'm looking to achieve.

Comment: More than doubly confused now that you say you want to *"group so you can query the data"*. This is just not how things work unless your intent is to re-write the collection into another format so you can query, and then it doesn't really make sense as to what the purpose is. You seem to be explaining your approach to solving but not actually the problem you need to solve and why. Hence you aren't asking the right questions for the right answers.

Comment: @BlakesSeven let's say I have a collection called `identity` which for any given visitor to my site will contain multiple documents, one for each source of data about that visitor. each of these `identity` documents will tell me what data `provider` they contain data from and what `collection` from that provider the data represents. I want to unify that data (combine documents for each visitor), and query across the unified data to  get a count of different types of individuals. does this clarify? let me know if this is still unclear